# mac address collision

Tags: rom-flashing, mac-address

## The setting:

I have two identical phones: Samsung Galaxy S5 neo (SM-G903F). Due to various reasons (in one I tried Lineage OS, the other I had to reinstall) and crashed backups made by TWRP I ended up having to flash stock ROM to both of them. I installed the latest **same** image downloaded from https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-s5-neo/SM-G903F/

The ROM is NOT rooted, the Knox reports no flags - just as if it was a freshly bought phone.

## The problem:

After a while I discovered that **both of them have the same MAC address** and therefore I cannot have them both connected to my home WiFi at the same time - both are assigned same IP address by router and in the end none of them has access to the internet. However, one connection at the time works.

Same goes with bluetooth pairing - when I connect one phone to a speaker and then disconnects, I cannot then pair the other phone with same speaker.

## Questions:

1. How is that even possible? I thought MAC address is tied to **hardware** not ROM? Is there other possible cause? I didn't have this problem before I started flashing.
2. How can I solve the problem of assigning same IP?
3. I'm aware of MAC spoofers. Nonetheless, is there an option that doesn't require rooting?

Comment: If it's necessary, I can reflash one of the device.